# why is the html image right next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I want to display two images but why are they right next each other when I change image size to 300px even with display property inline-block? Shouldn't the imagine be one on top of the other? How did the image size changed the position of the image even with inline-block property?

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

p {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-container {}

.middle-container {}

.bottom-containter {}

.top-cloud {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bottom-cloud {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mountain {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <img class='top-cloud' src="image/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
  <h1>Hi, this is Jin</h1>
  <p>a<span class="pro">Pro</span>grammer, Baller</p>
  <img class='bottom-cloud' src="image/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
  <img class='mountain' src="image/mountian.png" alt="mountain-image">
</div>

<div class="middle-container"></div>

<div class="bottom-containter"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: try to use less whitespaces in you code example, it hard to read

Comment: ```display: block``` produces a linebreak.  ```display: inline-block``` does not.

Comment: here is an explaning for using the display selecter https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inline-block_span1

Comment: thanks for all the advice!  I saw what was my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Apply to the mountain element a margin in the left.

```
.mountain {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0 0 0 2em;
}
```